# geom_bar x and y values do not match on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, geom-bar

I have a list of dataframes that I am trying to make bar plots from using a for loop.

This is the list if data frames

```
test2<- list(WBq2, WSq2, Kq2, Nq2, Fq2, LHq2, Lynq2, Mq2, NEq2, WB2q2, MCq2,  Cq2, M2q2, NE2q2, K2q2, N2q2, MC2q2, C2q2, F2q2, LH2q2, GPq2 )
```

Each data frame looks like this- K2q2.

```
 date market Question Responses
9  31-Jul     K2       $0         4
10 31-Jul     K2    $1-10        26
11 31-Jul     K2   $11-25        88
12 31-Jul     K2   $26-50        43
13 31-Jul     K2  $51-100        11
14 31-Jul     K2    $100+         2
```

This is the vector of names I am using

```
names2 <- c('WestBroadway', "West Side", "Kingfield","Nokomis", "Fulton",    "Linden Hills", "Lyndale", "Midtown", "Northeast", "West Broadway2", "Mill City", "Camden", "Midtown2", "Northeast2", "Kingfield2", "Nokomis2", "Mill City2", "Camden2", "Fulton2", "Linden Hills2", "Govenors Plaza" )
```

This is my for loop:

```
for (i in test2){
  for (j in names2){
  i$Question <- factor(i$Question, levels = i$Question)
  plot <- ggplot(data = i, aes(x = Question, y = Responses)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    ggtitle(j) + 
    labs(x="How much did you spend or plan on spending at the market today?", y= "Responses") 
  ggsave(filename=paste(j,"Q22",".pdf",sep=""), plot=plot, device = "pdf")
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is when I run this loop the plots are produced by the x labels (Question) do not match to the y labels (Response). How do you you get these two values to stick together like they are in the K2q2 dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: What is in `names2`? Have you tried updating the `Question` variable in the first `for` loop rather than in the second `for` loop as you have now?

Comment: You're printing your plots several time (as many time as the length of `names2`), but with the same name. So you only get the values from the last dataframe

Comment: names2 <- c('WestBroadway', "West Side", "Kingfield","Nokomis", "Fulton", "Linden Hills", "Lyndale", "Midtown", "Northeast", "West Broadway2", "Mill City", "Camden", "Midtown2", "Northeast2", "Kingfield2", "Nokomis2", "Mill City2", "Camden2", "Fulton2", "Linden Hills2", "Govenors Plaza" )

Comment: I feel like this should be way simpler than I am making it!

Comment: You want `i` in your filename. That way you won't overwrite the same files for each data frame.

Comment: does `length(names2) == length(test2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it may be difficult to make a solution. Try this, if it works that's great, if it doesn't I'll remove it.

```
j = 1 #initialize counter
for (i in test2){

  i$Question <- factor(i$Question, levels = i$Question)
  plot <- ggplot(data = i, aes(x = Question, y = Responses)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    ggtitle(names2[j]) + 
    labs(x="How much did you spend or plan on spending at the market today?", y= "Responses") 
  ggsave(filename=paste(names2[j], "Q22", ".pdf", sep=""), 
         plot=plot, device = "pdf")

j = j + 1 #update counter

}
```